# How to define a kind-of-block that is used specifically for variable scoping

Tags: ruby

## Update:

I've just written this small gem: [var_block](https://github.com/jrpolidario/var_block) Hope it helps! :)

### Question:

- Is there a way to do something like below?

  ```
  vegetable = 'bean'

  # is there a ruby way equivalent to this "with" that I just wrote?
  with( fruit: -> {'apple'} ) do
    puts vegetable
    puts fruit
  end
  # => 'bean'
  # => 'fruit'

  puts vegetable
  # => 'bean'
  puts fruit
  # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `fruit'
  ```
- I am looking for a way for a variable to be only defined inside this "kind-of-block" (in this example: `fruit` variable), but at the same time is executed in the context outside of that block (like as if you just copy all code inside that block, and paste it outside of that block)

### Usage:

- Hopefully, I could simplify "nested-logic" codes from my Rails app into something like (**note**: this is simplified use-case):

  ```
  # app/models/user.rb
  has_many :apples
  validates :name, presence: true

  with(has_an_apple: -> { apples.present? ) do
    validate :should_have_a_cart, if: { has_an_apple }

    with(has_a_ripe_apple: -> { apples.ripe.present? ) do
      validate :should_have_energy_to_harvest_apples, if: -> { has_an_apple && has_a_ripe_apple }
    end

    with(has_a_rotten_apple: -> { apples.rotten.present? ) do
      validate :should_have_energy_to_dispose_of_rotten_apples, if: -> { has_an_apple && has_a_rotten_apple }
    end
  end
  ```

### Remarks:

- I vaguely remember that long time ago, I have read something like this exists in ruby, but I couldn't really remember it now, even after countless search on the internet.
- Arguably, it might have been cleaner to not use this "blocks", and just write all my `validates` above having the same indentations, and looks cleaner, but I want to group "stuff" up now that I noticed I have now lots of validations having repetitive `if` conditions, and that it's easier for me to now understand it in this way as I can immediately see the "indents" and the "blocks" to allow me to focus one particular scenario after another.

### Attempts:

```
# begin ... end does not seem to work as the variable can still be accessed outside it
begin
  fruit = 'apple'
  puts fruit
end
# => 'apple'

puts fruit
# => 'apple'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `Proc` (or lambda), in the same way that encapsulation is implemented in, say, ECMAScript or Scheme:

```
vegetable = 'bean'

-> fruit = 'apple' {
  puts vegetable
  puts fruit
}.()
# bean
# apple

puts vegetable
# bean

puts fruit
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `fruit'
```

However, in general, it is considered to be more idiomatic to not write so complex code that you cannot keep track of your local variables anymore.

Comment: I see. I was hoping there might be something built-in to Ruby though. But, thanks! :) I'll use your code and extend/define it as some-method (though will be only native to my app)

Comment: I think instead of user `.()` (that internally call method named `call` and it is completely ruby thing) we should call it explicitly like `.call` to execute proc that make code more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I've just written this small gem: [var_block](https://github.com/jrpolidario/var_block) Hope it helps! :)

### Update:

You may also be interested in ruby's `tap` method:

#### Example

```
vars = { fruit: 'apple' }

{ fruit: 'apple', vegetable: 'bean' }.tap do |vars|
  puts vars[:fruit]
  puts vars[:vegetable]
end
# => 'apple'
# => 'bean'

puts vars[:fruit]
# => apple
puts vars[:vegetable]
# => nil
```

However in my particular case, it is limited to be used only like below:

```
( -> { is_admin? } ).tap do |condition|
  validates :email, presence: true, if: condition
  validates :address, presence: true, if: condition
end
```

but you cannot use it like below (won't work):

```
( -> { is_admin? } ).tap do |condition|
  validates :email, presence: true, if: -> condition
  validates :address, presence: true, if: -> condition
end
```

### Updated:

However, this actually works:

```
( -> (this) { this.is_admin? } ).tap do |condition|
  validates :email, presence: true, if: -> { condition.(self) }
  validates :address, presence: true, if: -> { condition.(self) }
end
```

... although for nested multiple conditions, you'll have to write each of them inside the `if:` block. Therefore, this is now only where my gem may be of some use.